# My 52 year-old husband owns a rental property. Sell? When?

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax, rental-property

My husband owns a house we rent. The tenants are great, but my husband is taking a cash flow loss (less than $400/mo). However, the equity is rising nicely - 14% last year, 54% over the last 5. I want him to easily pay off or pay down the mortgage I'm carrying on my house so he'll be comfortable if/when I die. He's 52 years old and I'm also concerned about capital gains, which I worry he'll get hit with inheritance taxes since my house is worth over a million dollars. My question is should we sell the rental, and if so, when is the best time for tax purposes?

Comment: Sorry, there's some info in the body of your post but what is your actual question? If you're asking whether / when to sell the rental property then that is purely opinion-based and will be closed on this site. You would need to consult a financial advisor who can take your complete circumstances into account and provide personalised advice. Alternatively, if you can edit your post to be more about factual questions that can be answered here (for example, what are the taxes that could be applicable) then you will also need to specify where you are as tax laws vary around the world.

Comment: $400/month is pretty decent cash flow for a rental these days. But whether you sell involves a lot of factors, many of them based on your personal subjectivity. This question isn't  rally a good fit for the site without a more specific question.

Comment: Assuming you're both US citizens, there's no inheritance tax between spouses: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/u/unlimited-marital-deduction.asp

Comment: Tip: Tax questions should have a country tag.